Determining a conformal mapping to the unit disk
Let
$$\Omega = \left\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z - 1| > 1, |z - 2| < 2, \Im(z) > 0\right\}.$$
We want to determine a conformal map which maps $\Omega$ to the unit disk. We solved it by composing $5$ transformations (mapping $\Omega$ to a half-strip by an inversion, upper half-disk, first quadrant, upper half-plane...). Is there a simpler way to solve it in order to not defining all these functions and compositions?

The chain of the fractional linear map of the two circles tangent at $z=0$ to a half strip with $0\to \infty$, vertical half strip to half plane by $w=\sinh z$ and the standard fractional map from half plane to unit disk is probably the minimum.
The sin function maps the strip $$x\in (-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}), y\ge 0$$ to the upper half plane.
With a little help of computational AI
   map[x_, y_] = ComplexExpand[Through[{Re, Im}[ Sin[x + I y] ] ]]

$$\{x,y\} \mapsto \{\sin (x) \cosh (y),\cos (x) \sinh (y)\}$$
   ParametricPlot[
            {Table[map[x, 2 s], {x, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2, 0.3}], 
             Table[map[-\[Pi]/2 + \[Pi] s, y], {y, 0, 2, 0.3}]}, 
             {s, 0, 1 }]


Thats of course the upper half of elliptic coordinates chart.

How would one prove that vertical half strip maps to half plane by the hyperbolic sine?
